# FatFs - f_open Hard Fault

Tags: c, stm32, fatfs

I am trying to write some data on SD card connected with SPI (I am using a STM32F303).

I can mount the SD card but when I want to create a file and open it I get a Hard Fault issue at line 3398 in function f_open of the file ff.c:

```
3395: fp->obj.fs = fs;      /* Validate the file object */
3396: fp->obj.id = fs->id;
3397: fp->flag = mode;      /* Set file access mode */
3398: fp->err = 0;          /* Clear error flag */
3399: fp->sect = 0;         /* Invalidate current data sector */
3400: fp->fptr = 0;         /* Set file pointer top of the file */
```

Have you ever got this type of issue ? And how did you fix it ?

Thanks
Jordan

Comment: Seems as unaligned access, check address of buffer where you point `fp` struct.

Comment: I am an idiot, it was that, I didn't initialize my pointer structure.

Comment: @imbearr It can't be unaligned access here the problem. CPU is Cortex-M4 which supports unaligned access.